# React - one event handler to toggle one of multiple similar elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to practice React by rebuilding an agency website. I'm working on a section which has staff images, and clicking one of those images opens the relevant staff bio in a modal. The images and the bios are in separate containing divs.

It feels like I should be able to write one event handler that finds and opens the relevant bio depending on which image is clicked (maybe using something like the data attribute?), but I can't figure out what I'd need to add.

Currently I just have a click handler which toggles a piece of 'active' state. That state is then added as a className to toggle whether the modal is showing. Problem of course being that it doesn't differentiate between bios, so they all show regardless which bio is clicked on.

In case it's useful, here is my 'staff bio' component:

```
const StaffBio = (props) => {
return (
    <div className={`teamMemberOverlay ${props.active}`} onClick={props.onClick}>
        <div className="teamMemberExpanded">
            <h6>{props.name}</h6>
            <div className="seperator"></div>
            <p className="title">{props.title}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
);
}
```

Which is being used like this:

```
<StaffBio name="NAME HERE" title="TITLE HERE" active={this.state.active} onClick={this.showBio} />
```

So far I've got the images set up as follows:

```
<img src={PaulIllustration} className="staffPhoto" onClick={this.showBio} />
```

And lastly, my event handler:

```
showBio() {
    let toggle = this.state.active === 'is-active' ? '' : 'is-active';
    this.setState({active: toggle});
}
```

Comment: Could you post the component where the `showBio` method is defined?

Answer (score 1):

```
class AboutUsSlider extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.showBio = this.showBio.bind(this)
    this.next = this.next.bind(this)

    this.state = { active: null }
}

next() {
  this.refs.slider.slickNext()
}

showBio(id) {
  this.setState({active: id});
}
hideBio(){
  this.setState({active: null});
}

render() {
  var settings = {...}
  const people = [{name: 'Paul', title: 'some title'}, {name: 'Ben', title: 'other'}, ...];

return (
  <div>
  <Slider ref="slider" {...settings}>
    <div className="sliderPage">
      <h2>Meet our team</h2>
      <div className="seperator"></div>
      <div className="teamPhotos">
      { // When setting the index, you should use something unique, I'll use the name here.
       people.map((p, index) => 
           <img key={p.name} src={`${p.name} + 'Illustration'`} className="staffPhoto" onClick={() => this.showBio(index)}) />
      }
      </div>
      <Button BGColor="#009ECC" text="Our process" onClick={this.next} />
    </div>
  </Slider>
  { this.state.active && <StaffBio name={people[this.state.active]} title={people[this.state.active].title} onClick={this.hideBio}/>
  </div>
  )
}
```

EDITED

There are a couple of things you can do.

Each person probably has an id to identify it. So you could modify your `showBio` to look like this:

```
showBio(id) {
  this.setState({ active: id })
}
```

This way, you get which person is currently active in your state.

You also need to change your `img`

```
<img src={PaulIllustration} className="staffPhoto" onClick={() => this.showBio(PaulId)} />
```

Where `PaulId` would be different for each person.

And your `StaffBio`:

```
<StaffBio name="NAME HERE" title="TITLE HERE" active={this.state.active == personId} onClick={this.showBio} />


const StaffBio = (props) => {
  return (
  <div className={`teamMemberOverlay ${props.active ? 'is-active' : ''}`} onClick={props.onClick}>
    <div className="teamMemberExpanded">
        <h6>{props.name}</h6>
        <div className="seperator"></div>
        <p className="title">{props.title}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. When implementing this I get 'PaulId' is not defined and 'personId' is not defined. Probably missing something very obvious as my head is a bit scrambled! Here's the component showBio is defined in: https://jsfiddle.net/nannyro5/1/

Comment: Where are you getting your data? Or is it just static? If it is static, you could use indexes as Ids. I'll update my answer with the ShowBio component

Comment: It's just static for now yes - thank you! Were it to be pulled in from elsewhere, I was thinking it'd be best to map over the data and assign a key that way? Though that's a separate question I know..!

Comment: I edited the answer. Yes, you should usually map over the data

Comment: Brilliant way of displaying the staff images - thank you! Instead of the StaffBios though, I'm getting the number '0' between <!-- react-text --> comments. Peculiar but I guess this is something I'm doing wrong, so I'll try to figure that out...